# Parsing ASCII file efficiently in Haskell

Tags: haskell, file-io, text-parsing

I wanted to reimplement some of my ASCII parsers in Haskell since I thought I could gain some speed. However, even a simple "grep and count" is much slower than a sloppy Python implementation.

Can someone explain me why and how to do it correctly?

So the task is, count the lines which starts with the string "foo".

My very basic **Python** implementation:

```
with open("foo.txt", 'r') as f:
    print len([line for line in f.readlines() if line.startswith('foo')])
```

And the **Haskell** version:

```
import System.IO 
import Data.List

countFoos :: String -> Int
countFoos str = length $ filter (isPrefixOf "foo") (lines str)

main = do
    contents <- readFile "foo.txt"
    putStr (show $ countFoos contents)
```

Running both with `time` on a ~600MB file with 17001895 lines reveals that the **Python implementation is almost 4 times faster than the Haskell** one (running on my MacBook Pro Retina 2015 with PCIe SSD):

```
> $ time ./FooCounter                                                           
1770./FooCounter  20.92s user 0.62s system 98% cpu 21.858 total

> $ time python foo_counter.py                                                   
1770
python foo_counter.py  5.19s user 1.01s system 97% cpu 6.332 total
```

Compared to unix command line tools:

```
> $ time grep -c foo foo.txt                                                     
1770
grep -c foo foo.txt   4.87s user 0.10s system 99% cpu 4.972 total

> $ time fgrep -c foo foo.txt                                                     
1770
fgrep -c foo foo.txt  6.21s user 0.10s system 99% cpu 6.319 total

> $ time egrep -c foo foo.txt                                                     
1770
egrep -c foo foo.txt  6.21s user 0.11s system 99% cpu 6.317 total
```

Any ideas?

**UPDATE:**

Using András Kovács' implementation (`ByteString`), I got it under half a second!

```
> $ time ./FooCounter                                                                                                               
1770
./EvtReader  0.47s user 0.48s system 97% cpu 0.964 total
```

Comment: Please compile with -O2 if you haven't.

Comment: Don't use `String`. Use either `ByteString` or (more likely) `Text`. The `String` type is very flexible, but very inefficient for just about everything.

Comment: @AndrásKovács I forgot to mention, I did compile it with -O2. Actually it doesn't make a difference :-\ Anyway: köszi

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid but `readFile` has `readFile :: FilePath -> IO String`. How should I force using `ByteString` or `Text`?

Comment: @septi Have a look in `Data.Text.IO`. You'll find another `readFile` function that returns a `Text` instead.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I benchmarked the following solution:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as B

main =
  print . length . filter (B.isPrefixOf "foo") . B.lines =<< B.readFile "test.txt"
```

`text.txt` is a 170 MB file with 8 million lines, and half of the lines start with "foo". I compiled with GHC 7.10 and `-O2 -fllvm`.

The `ByteString` version ran in **0.27** seconds, while the original version ran in **5.16** seconds.

However, the strict `ByteString` version uses 170 MB memory loading the full file. Changing the import to `Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8` I got **0.39** sec runtime and 1 MB memory usage.

Comment: Wow, that's impressive. Got under half a second with that!

Comment: Does this read the whole file into memory? Since I also need to parse files larger than 10GB…

Comment: Yes, it loads everything. See the edit of the answer.

Answer (score 5):

Your Haskell version uses the type `String` to represent the text of the file. `String` is an alias for `[Char]` which is a linked list of characters. That's not a good representation for large strings.

Try using the [text](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/text) package instead. It represents strings as arrays (in the `Data.Text.*` modules) or as linked lists of arrays (in the `Data.Text.Lazy.*` modules). To port your existing code, you probably want the latter, because I guess you don't want to load the full 600MB file into memory at once. Look in the [`Data.Text.Lazy`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/text/docs/Data-Text-Lazy.html) and [`Data.Text.Lazy.IO`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/text/docs/Data-Text-Lazy-IO.html) modules for variants of the `readFile`, `filter`, `isPrefixOf` etc. functions you're using.

If you're sure you only want to support ASCII, you can also look into using the [`bytestring`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring) package instead of the `text` package.